# Access individual qubits of a quantum circuit in qiskit by qubit name

Tags: qiskit

I am very new to quantum computing and only recently started learning Qiskit, so the question may sound a bit silly.

Essentially, when I create a `QuantumCircuit` object, I want to be able to access an individual qubit of the quantum circuit by the name of the qubit. So far, I have looked at various sources online, but none of them helped me.

More concretely, given a `QuantumCircuit` object, say `qc`, I want to do the following:

```
q = qc['p0'] # Assume that p0 is a qubit name
```

Also, suppose I have to add a quantum gate to one or more qubits in the quantum circuit. Currently, I know how to do this using the qubit indices in the quantum circuit. But can I do this using the qubit names?

Change

```
qc.append(HGate(), [0])
```

to something like

```
qc.append(HGate(), ['p0']) # p0 is a qubit name
```

Are there any methods to achieve what I want? Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

There might be a more elegant solution, but this is what I came up with.

1. Define the quantum registers with custom names

   ```
   from qiskit.circuit import QuantumRegister
   q0 = QuantumRegister(1, 'Alice')
   q1 = QuantumRegister(1, 'Bob')
   ```
2. Construct the circuit

   ```
   from qiskit import QuantumCircuit

   qc = QuantumCircuit(q0, q1)
   ```
3. Define a custom function to get the qubits by name

   ```
   def get_qubit_by_name(qc, name):
       for qubit in qc.qubits:
           if qubit.register.name == name:
               return qubit
   ```

Then you could do something like

```
q2 = get_qubit_by_name(qc, 'Alice')
```

However, `q0` and `q2` are two different `Qubit` objects (`q1 != q2`). Then you can call

```
qc.append(HGate(), [get_qubit_by_name(qc, 'Alice')])
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, but as far as I know, the `register` function has been deprecated as of Qiskit version 0.17 and will be removed soon (you can see it in the API documentation [here](https://docs.quantum.ibm.com/api/qiskit/qiskit.circuit.Qubit#register)). Another way I found was using [`find_bit`](https://docs.quantum.ibm.com/api/qiskit/qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit#find_bit), but that seems very convoluted. Any other elegant method?

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer to my question, which builds from what [@squareroottwo](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/users/23525/squareroottwo) suggested in their response.

Basically, given a `QuantumCircuit` `qc`, a `QuantumRegister` `qr` containing one qubit, I can use the `find_bit` method of `QuantumCircuit` in this way:

```
def get_qubit_index(qc: QuantumCircuit, qr: QuantumRegister):
  return qc.find_bit(qr[0]).index
```

If the `QuantumRegister` contains more than one qubit, then I can specify the index of the qubit *in* the `QuantumRegister` when I call the above function instead of hard-coding index 0.

If anyone has any other elegant answers, please post them as well!